# generating a PDF, using PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I am creating a website for some land developers and the want to be able to generate an invoice with dynamic content, I tried FPDF but I found it too time consuming, difficult and tiresome to learn in order to create the invoice am looking for, is there an easier way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

The [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org) library is built on FPDF and has numerous improvements (in my opinion). If you want to generate truly customisable PDFs you won't find anything more simple. There is a learning curve but since it's a popular library you'll find solid documentation and answers to most of your questions